# Ruby http-2 implementation: how does eof work?

Tags: ruby, sockets, http2

In the [example](https://github.com/igrigorik/http-2/blob/master/example/client.rb) client implementation of the Ruby http-2 gem there is a section of code at the bottom for reading data from the socket:

```
while !sock.closed? && !sock.eof?
  data = sock.read_nonblock(1024)
  # puts "Received bytes: #{data.unpack("H*").first}"

  begin
    conn << data
  rescue => e
    puts "#{e.class} exception: #{e.message} - closing socket."
    e.backtrace.each { |l| puts "\t" + l }
    sock.close
  end
end
```

I don't understand how this loop terminates.  Presumably an eof is picked up from the socket, but I don't understand how.  It's not like the server is going to know which stream is the final one.

Assuming no errors, how does this loop come to an end?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether it is a secure connection or not. If it is ***not*** a secure connection, then sock is an instance of `TCPSocket`.

The `#eof?` method is defined on the IO class. The hierarchy is:

TCPSocket < IPSocket < BasicSocket < IO

IO is a class that is the ancestor of both sockets and the File class. It has generalized IO methods, that I think work differently on the specific implementation.

If the socket is closed or there is an error, then the socket may be in an ***eof-like*** state. That is, there is no more data to read. From [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-eof-3F):

> `#eof?` Returns true if ios is at end of file that means there are no more data to read.

I'm don't know under what conditions the socket would be eof and not closed, but this a higher-level explanation. You could dig into the `eof?` implementation to see more details, and also sockets in general. In my experience, classes like TCPSocket are are wrappers around system implementations.

Comment: Do you know how the loop typically comes to an end?